# Format of metadata json for ERC721

Tags: nft, erc-721, opensea

I deployed a simple NFT contract based on the nibbstack ERC721 implementation

For testing purposes I hardcoded the ipfs link into the contract.
The mint function looks like this, for testing purposes everyone who send 100 Wei can get an NFT

```
function mint() public payable {
         require(msg.value == 100, "Send 100 Wei");
         super._mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
         super._setTokenUri(tokenId, nfts[0]);
         tokenId++;
    }
```

The ipfs are hardcoded like this:

```
string[] nfts = ["https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUFbUjAifv9GwJo7ufTB5sccnrNqELhDMafoEmZdPPng7"];
```

the ipfs link points to a json file that looks like this (I picked it from the ipfs documentation):

```
{
    "name": "NFT Art",
    "description": "This image shows the true nature of NFT.",
    "image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQEVVLJUR1WLN15S49rzDJsSP7za9DxeqpUzWuG4aondg",
}
```

However, format must be wrong, I can never view the image.
Here is the opensea site for an example deployment on the Goerli testnet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the ERC721 Metadata JSON Schema from the [ERC721 token standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `tokenURI(tokenId)` nor `_baseURI()` functions.

If you are using smart contract libs like `@openzeppelin`, you will find that this function `tokenURI(tokenId)` returns a URL of the NFT of the given tokenId.

You need to modify (override) it to return the link for the NFT, I will leave an example.

```
string constant TOKEN_URI = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUFbUjAifv9GwJo7ufTB5sccnrNqELhDMafoEmZdPPng7";

function tokenURI(uint256 /* tokenId */) public pure override returns (string memory) {
    return TOKEN_URI;
}
```

This is just a simple demo, you can use the tokenId that is passed as a parameter to the function to return different URLs for different NFTs.